# One database connection to each thread?

Tags: java, database, multithreading, postgresql, connection

I making a webcrawler and each thread makes insertion of pages and links constantly. I must have a database connection per thread or share one connection to them?

Comment: yes, either is possible depending your requirements.

Comment: Someone hava a good tutorial about pool connections? If for Java and PostgreSQL is better. It's a new concept for me and I know nothing.

Comment: Most JDBC drivers have pool support built in.  You only need an additional pool if you want to control it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would typically handle this situation using some sort of database connection pool, which can manage the lifetime of your database connections for you. In Java, the [Apache Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) library is often used for this, although if you are using other frameworks, they may have that functionality built in.

Comment: Some example using PostgreSQL? The database has influence in the use of the Apache Commons DBCP?

Comment: You would use the Postgres JDBC driver [1], and connect via JDBC. [1] http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

Comment: No, each thread asks the connection pool for a connection, uses it as needed, and then closes it when it's done, so it can go back into the pool.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider decoupling the crawling with the database i/o with a producer consumer pattern if feasible. This would allow you to later tune the number of crawler threads (producers) and database connection-i/o threads (consumers). You can use a bounded blocking queue to transfer/distribute the work from the crawlers to the writers.

Comment: And what performance gain is there from separating the database connection in its own consumer thread. I assume you are referring to something like http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: Decoupling crawling from database writes just gives an opportunity for tuning. The number of crawlers not necessarily == number of db writers.